# Warning 10: this expression should have type unit

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to create a list of functions in Ocaml but I keep getting a warning.  Any idea why?

let f = [fun x -> -x;fun x -> x+2;fun x -> x*x]

Answer (score 10):

The semi-colon is also used to end functions that are used for their side-effects. The warning comes about when the return type of these functions is not `unit` (in this case `int`); they are just warnings since you *may* have intended to only use the side-effects, normally it is an error. This is an aside, but to suppress these warnings programmatically and safely use the `ignore` function, as in `ignore (x+2);`.

Back to your problem, in it (and expanding the semi-colons to their equivalence; and modifying the variables for each function) you are actually writing,

```
(fun x -> 
    let _ = -x in
    (fun y -> 
        let _ = y+2 in 
        (fun z -> z*z)))
```

Or, another example as gasche points out,

```
(fun x -> 
    -x;
    (fun y -> 
        y+2;
        (fun z -> z*z)))
```

You can tell from the type returned, `(int -> int -> int -> int) list` that something is instantly amiss from your intentions. You'll need to add parenthesis around each, like `(fun x -> x+2);` to actually create a list.

Comment: Expanding semicolons into something doesn't make the problem clearer. To explain wrong precedence or associativity to a beginner, you need only use parentheses: `[fun x -> (-x; fun x -> x+2; (fun x -> x*x))]`.

Comment: Seems like it's pretty tricky to explain why this is a list of two things: `[3; 4]`, but this is a list of one thing: `[fun x -> 3; fun x -> 4]`.  It's not about the relative precedence of `[]` and `;` so much as the fact that `fun` creates an environment where `;` has higher predecence than usual (or something like this).

Comment: the correct explanation is that `fun` has the lowest precedence, so swallows the `;` (the precedence of `[]` is irrelevant since it is a bracket; things can't "jump" out of the bracket). See http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html (scroll down to the table)

Comment: Certainly precedence is a blunt tool for reasoning about syntax.  I was just thinking about the fact that `[(3;4)]` is different from `[3;4]`.  So there's an effect similar to precedence.  The `[]` and `;` kind of work together to make something vaguely operator-like.  You could argue it's not helpful to look at it this way.  I wouldn't disagree.